# Urban Airship Phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm developing an application using the phonegap AU plugin.
The build process runs via Phonegap Build and successfully occurs.
However when I try to open the application, I am getting the following error:

```
W/PackageParser( 6962): No actions in intent filter at     /storage/emulated/0/Download/PushPG-debug.apk Binary XML file line #15 
D/RCPManagerService( 816): PackageReceiver onReceive() bundle Bundle[{com.urbanairship.autopilot=com.urbanairship.phonegap.PushAutopilot, com.google.android.gms.version=6587000}] 
I/PCWCLIENTTRACE_PushUtil( 6564): SPPPushClient is installed : true 
I/PCWCLIENTTRACE_PushUtil( 6564): sales region : global 
I/PCWCLIENTTRACE_PushUtil( 6564): getPushTypeList : [SPP, GCM] 
I/dalvikvm( 7257): Could not find method android.support.v4.app.NotificationManagerCompat.from, referenced from method com.urbanairship.push.PushManager.<init> 
I/dalvikvm( 7257): Could not find method android.support.v4.app.NotificationManagerCompat.notify, referenced from method com.urbanairship.push.PushManager.show 
E/AndroidRuntime( 7257): at com.urbanairship.push.PushManager.<init>(PushManager.java:212) 
E/SPPClientService(13835): [[PushClientService]] F:false, D:false, E:false, T:false, S:true, R:false
```

In my config.xml I added the follow line:

My test Code:

```
document.addEventListener('urbanairship.registration', this.onUrbanAirshipRegistration, false);
onUrbanAirshipRegistration = function (event) { 
if (event.error) { 
console.log('there was an error registering for push notifications'); 
} else { 
console.log("Registered with ID: " + event.pushID); 
} 
app.receivedEvent('urbanairship.registration'); 
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Urban Airship does not provide support for Phonegap Build, though there is a plugin that you can install manually: https://github.com/urbanairship/phonegap-ua-push

Answer (score 0):

i think you add some code on wrong place. you can't add document.addeventlistner... in config.xml.

Please can you again go through following links carefully.

For documentation: http://docs.urbanairship.com/

For implimentation: https://github.com/urbanairship/phonegap-ua-push

Thanks.